# Combine Dynamic and Static Google Spreadsheet? Any ideas?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheet where columns A,B,C are pulled through our Master spreadsheet. We havey added columns D-G and started populating them, but they break, as soon as we remove some data from the Master Spreadsheet. All the data is out of sync once a change is made, as we're basically trying to combine dynamic and static data. Please note that we often remove rows from the Master spreadsheet.

Is there a way to "lock" the static data to the dynamic? So, for instance, if we remove cells A1, B1, C1, then cells D1, E1, F1, G1, are also removed?

Or if we sort columns A-C, the others get sorted too?

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, very polite.

Comment: How are you pulling data into the spreadsheet? Are you using built-in functions, Google Apps Scripts or the Google Sheets API?

Comment: The Spreadsheet is pulling from another Spreadsheet.